# Configure webapp context in Nexus OSS 3

Tags: nexus

I would like to change the webapp context of a Nexus OSS 3 installation to run on http://localhost:8081/nexus instead of http://localhost:8081.

[The documentation for version 2 is quite clear about how to do it](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html), but [the documentation for version 3](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#reverse-proxy) redirects to [this link to configure a Nexus "capability"](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/admin.html#admin-base-url), which mentions that

> The repository manager only uses this value to construct absolute URLs to your user interface inside of email notifications.

I'm not sure then that it's the correct option. And if it is, what value should I put? /nexus or full url https://serverPublicName/nexus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK next time i will read documentation more carefully...

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#config-context-path

8-s

Comment: Also note that there is a config option in the soon to be released 3.1 version that emulates the 2.x paths to repos.